# Alias option in SQL Query

Tags: sql, alias

```
select b.test_id,d.test_id from test b, test d
```

What could be the result on stated query. Either both the columns will result same one or different?

Answer (score 3):

You have the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) a.k.a [CROSS JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) of all rows.

> The cross join does not apply any predicate to filter records from the joined table.

For rows 1, 2, and 3 in test you will get exactly  this:

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
3,1
3,2
3,3
```

Answer (score 0):

you're going to get every possible combination of test_id in a cross join (cartesian product), the headers are the only things that's going to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Each possible combination will come

If table have 3 rows you can get 9 rows total.

### test

```
test_id 

1

2

3

1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
3,1
3,2
3,3
```